# How to add multiple jquery methods?

Tags: jquery

> How to get siblingsUntil jquery?

There is nextUntil, prevUntil but there is not siblingsUntil?

Suppose this html:

```
<ul>
   <li class="one sib">list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li class="three">list item 3</li>
   <li>list item 4</li>
   <li class="five sib">list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

From being at class "three":

By using nextUntil:

```
$('.three').nextUntil('.one').css('color','red');//colors to list item 4
```

By using prevUntil:

```
$('.three').prevUntil('.five').css('color','blue');//colors to list item 2
```

Now, likely that I couldn't do the following:

```
$('.three').siblingsUntil('.sib').css('color','green');//colors to list item 2 and 4
```

So, how can I get list item 2 and 4 from being at list item 3 as siblingsUntil?

> Solution:

Luckily, there is end() method and we can combine with nextUntil() and prevUntil():

```
$('.three').nextUntil('.five').css('color','red').end().prevUntil('.one').css('color','red');
```

But I'm not sure if there even easier way to accomplish the same.

> Now, real **question**:

We can add multiple selectors like this:

```
$(selector).add(another_selector).css('color','red');
```

I was wondering if there is someway that we can add jquery methods something like this:

```
$('.three').add($.nextUntil('.five'),$.prevUntil('.one')).css('color','red');
```

Comment: Have you actually tried you last line of code?

Comment: So you want to select all siblings except the current, first and last?

Comment: @vittore that doesn't work!

Comment: @Jack yes, but not actually first and last because the idea is that we can select the class until what should be selected.

Comment: So you will be using two classes to indicate the lower and upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .add() like

```
var $el = $('.three');
$el.nextUntil('.five').add($el.prevUntil('.one')).addBack().css('color', 'red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6c92s/)

Answer (score 1):

You could start with an empty set and then add each subset:

```
var $three = $('.three');

$()
  .add($three.prevUntil('.one'))
  .add($three.nextUntil('.five'))
  .css('color','red');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/zedal/2/)

Comment: this one is easier. But it's selecting to .three also. see @Arun's fiddle that I wanted to do.

Comment: @C-link Updated, the temporary variable seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $3 = $('.three')

, all2to4 = $3.add($3.nextUntil('.five')).add($3.prevUntil('.one'))
```

`$(selector).add()` has version accepting elements - http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-elements